# C++ Boolean Algebra

Tags: c++, boolean-operations

I have declared some variable as Boolean and I was hoping that C++ would know what to do when I did some boolean addition but it's not happening the way I would like it to. How do I get it to work.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
bool x,j;
x=0;
j=1;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
cout << x;
x=x+j;
}
return 0;
}
```

I am getting the output as

```
011111111
```

whereas I was hoping to get

```
0101010101
```

I was hoping that Boolean variables would mod out by 2. So if

```
x=1 then
x+1 = 0
x+1+1=1
x+1+1+1=0
```

and so on.

Am I confusing boolean algebra with base-2 algebra?

Thanks

Comment: "Am I confusing boolean algebra with base-2 algebra?" - yes.

Comment: A `bool` is supposed to be `true` or `false`, but sinse you are using it as if it was a number, it will behave just like an `int` or maybe a `char`. In any case assigning it the value `2` will make its value be `2`, nothing is cropping it to have only 1 significant bit.

Comment: @Havenard: a `bool` cannot have value 2 in any meaningful way.  Many compilers will in fact force a byte to contain the number 1 if you assign 2 to a `bool`.  In any case, `bool(2) == bool(1)` is guaranteed.

Comment: Have you thought perhaps of using the infinitely simpler `x = !x`? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool x,j;
x=x+j;
```

This statement automatically promotes `x` and `j` to type `int` before adding them.  Then the assignment converts back to `bool` in the usual way: `0` becomes `false`, but any other number , including 2, becomes `true`.

You can get Z_2 addition by using the `^` (xor) operator instead:

```
x = x^j;
```

Answer (score 2):

C/C++ provide a range of bitwise operators: `&`, `|`, `^`, `~`, which generally work on booleans because true is converted to the integer 1 and false to 0.

But you can also use real boolean operators:

- `&&`  conjunction
- `||`  disjunction
- `!=`  exclusive or (what you regard as addition)
- `!`   not